# Condition based dependency injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am using strategy design pattern and want to inject different dependencies based on some conditions.

```
public interface strategy {
    public void task();
}

public class concreteStrategyOne implements strategy {
    public void task() {
        //task strategy one
    }
}

public class concreteStrategyTwo implements strategy {
    public void task() {
        //task strategy two
    }
}

public class taskInHand {

    private Strategy strategyImpl;

    @Inject
    public taskInHand(Strategy strategyImpl){
        this.strategy = strategyImpl;
    }

    public void use(Object obj) {

      if(obj.get("something") == 1){
            strategyImpl.task();
            // I want to call task() implemented in concreteStrategyOne 
      }
      else if(obj.get("something") == 2){
            strategtImpl.task()
            // I want to call task() implemented in concreteStrategyTwo
      }
}

}
```

I know I can used `@Named` annotation in a constructor to bind specific classes while injecting but I want to inject different dependencies according the conditions mentioned above.

So, to elaborate.. `if(object.get("something")) returns 1`, then I would want to run `task()` implemented in `concreteStrategyOne`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `StrategyFactory`

```java
public Class StrategyFactory {
    @Inject
    // Strategy one impl here
    private Strategy strategyOne;

    @Inject
    // Strategy two impl here
    private Strategy strategyTwo;

    public Strategy getStrategy(String something) {
        if (something.equals("some condition")) {
            return strategyOne;
        } else {
            return strategytwo;
        }
    }
}
```

Inject `StrategyFactory` in your `taskInHand` and pass on the attribute which decides the implementation to be used to `getStrategy()`

```java
public void use(Object obj) {
    strategyFactory.getStrategy(obj.get("something")).task();
}
```

Comment: How can we unit test this? I tried calling `strategyFactory.getStrategy("some condition")` but the result is `null` instead of an instance of Strategy type.

Comment: You can debug through and check. Possibly strategyOne,strategyTwo are not injected in your unit test.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Provider (I think that's what Guice calls them) that does the selection of the needed implementation and injects the needed one. But you'd need to provide the provider with all the information needed to make the decision. This might break encapsulation and a couple of other SOLID ideas.

The other option would be to inject a collection of all the implementations, iterate over the collection and have the implementations 'volounteer' if they find they're responsible or suited for the specific usecase.

More details about providers can be found in the [guice wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders).